# php - problem with set_error_handler

Tags: php

I'm trying to setup a custom landing error page in the event there is php errros, I'm using:

```
function xhandler($number,$string,$file,$line,$context){
  include('/path/to/error_text_page.tpl');
  exit;
}
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
set_error_handler('xhandler',E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

This isn't working though, anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How did you found that it doesn't work? Btw, what if file is not found in the handler's include?

Answer (score 1):

According to [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and to continue with Dr. Molle's reply:

> The following error types cannot be
>   handled with a user defined function:
>   E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR,
>   E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR,
>   E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of
>   E_STRICT raised in the file where
>   set_error_handler() is called.

That might explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that not every error-type can be handled by set_error_handler, e.g. parse/fatal errors.

Try

```
trigger_error("Testing xhandler", E_USER_ERROR);
```

for testing.